# Why Don't Hash Tables for Strings Simply Use This Collision-Less Function? (included below)

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

So I have a collision-less hash function (a very simple one) and I'm wondering why collision-less hash functions like this aren't used. I'm guessing that the reason must be that it takes up too much space or something, but I'd like to know the real answer.

Here's the function:

If you have a word w composed of n+1 characters ß<sub>n</sub> ß<sub>n-1</sub> ... ß<sub>1</sub> ß<sub>0</sub>, then define the hash function

**H(w) = 26<sup>n</sup> * ß<sub>n</sub> + 26<sup>n-1</sup> * ß<sub>n-1</sub> + ... + 26 * ß<sub>1</sub> + ß<sub>0</sub>.**

where, for instance, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ..., z = 26.

This function has no collisions, as it defines a one-to-one mapping between a String and the integers.

The issue of course is that as the length of the word increases, the hash code becomes very large.

A possible solution to this would be: split up long words and make each hash code a vector, with the second element pointing to the rest of the word (which in turn could point to another part of the word if it was split up more than once).

So my question is: why is this not implemented? Was the extra cost of memory not worth avoiding collisions? Was this method found to be poor for another reason? <del>Am I the first one to think of doing it this way?</del> (Just kidding about that last one.)

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but -- note that in Java, a `String` is *not* a sequence of lowercase English letters `a` through `z`, but rather, a sequence of UTF-16 codepoints, that is, of two-byte unsigned integers. So instead of `26`, you'd actually need to use `65536`. (Or `65537`, actually, if you want your hash-function to distinguish `"\0"` from `""`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So my question is: there must be a reason why this is not implemented?

Questions like that can only be answered definitively by the people who designed / implemented the APIs.

However, I can think of a number of reasons:

1. Your perfect hash function is impractical.  For strings longer than a relatively small number, the polynomial results in overflow in 32-bit integer arithmetic.  When that happens the function will no longer be perfect.
2. Even in the subset of the space where it gives perfect hashes, the spread of the values is large enough that the function is still impractical.  It is nuts to create a hash table whose base array has `2^31` elements.  And if you don't do that, you will get collisions when the perfect hash values are reduced (by `%`) to the size of the hash array.
3. Your function assumes that strings consist of letters (in one case) only.  You'd need to change `26` to `96` to support just the printable subset of ASCII.  And for real Java strings, it would need to be `65536` ... and your hash function would only work for 2 character strings!

Even if you could address the above (i.e. with a *practical* perfect hash function for a small set of strings), there is the problem that a `Map` type with a perfect hashed key has very limited utility.  So limited in fact that (AFAIK) neither the Guava, Apache Commons, Trove or Fastutils libraries have a specialist `Map` type that uses a perfect hash functions for strings.  (There are `Map` (or `Map`-like) implementations that allow the use of an external hash function ... but that's not what you are talking about.)

For the record, when people talk about perfect hash functions, they normally use the word *minimal*; i.e. *minimal perfect hash function*.

---

**UPDATE**

(Warning: this is tangential to the original question.  Read only if you are interested ...)

Supercat commented thus:

> It's also worth noting that there exists some code which unfortunately relies upon the exact behavior of the string hash function.

That is only "unfortunate" if you think the following is a problem with the way that the behaviour is defined.

> Were it not for that, it might be desirable to fix some more serious problems, like the fact that repeated calls to a string whose hashCode is zero will take a lot longer than repeated calls for strings with non-zero hash codes. That problem could be fixed cheaply via if (hash==0) hash=length; (since hash and length will likely be in a registers at that point, execution time should be minimal).

This assumes that we accept that the zero hash code case is a serious problem.  I put it to you that it is not a serious problem at all.

- If we assume that our Strings are created randomly, the probability that any given string has a zero hashcode is one in 2<sup>32</sup>.  That is a pretty small number ...
- If we do get a zero hashcode, the cost is that we recalculate the hashcode each time `hashcode()` is called.  But the cost of that is not that great.

In a typical scenario, the `hashcode()` method is used when a String is used in a hash table.  Lets assume that we are talking about the case where the key is a `String`, and that we are using the `HashMap` or `HashSet` class with the standard (OpenJDK 6/7) implementation.

- If a String is used just once to probe the hash table, its `hashcode` will be calculated once, irrespective of its value.
- If a String is incorporated into a hash table as a key, its `hashcode` will be calculated once ... because `HashMap` and `HashSet` cache the hashcode in the entry.  (In other words, the hashcode value that is cached in the `String` is irrelevant ... in this use-case)
- If the application is implemented to do something like "probe then add" or "probe then delete", and the String key used for probing has hashcode of zero, then you do the calculation twice instead of once.
- The only case where there is a significant performance concern is if you *repeatedly* probe hash tables using the same String object as a key ... and that key has a zero hashcode.

I would posit that if an application does repeated probes with the same key, the sensible thing to do would be to fix *that* rather than worrying about the on in 4 billion case that the hashcode is zero.

But I was assuming we are talking about "random" strings.  What if we dealing with strings that are *deliberately* chosen to have a zero hashcode in order to case performance problems ... or other problems that are a consequence of that.

Well lets look at the above analysis again.  Three of the four bullets said there as no problem at all.  Only the case where the application is repeatedly probing is problematic.  So the simple mitigation to the problem is to *design* the application so that *repeated* probing with the same `String` object doesn't need to happen.

(And lets step back a bit.  If someone is trying to cause performance problems with String keys, there are better ways to do it.  For instance, if they know what algorithm is used on the platform, they could pick a set of Strings of length `M` that are "almost equal" and that all hash to the same hash value.  Then arrange that `N` of these keys are added to the HashMap as keys.  Now, a probe with another key with the same properties will cause at least `N` String comparisons resulting in `O(N*M)` character comparisons.  That's potentially a much worse performance hit, and harder to mitigate by application programming.)

Finally, even if we accepted that this was a problem that required fixing by changing the `hashcode` method, there is another way to do it that does NOT involve changing the `String` spec.  Add an extra private `boolean` field to the `String` object so that `hashcode == 0` doesn't have an overloaded meaning!  (Sure, it makes String bigger ... but if the overloading is an important problem, that shouldn't matter.)

Comment: It's also worth noting that there exists some code which unfortunately relies upon the *exact* behavior of the string hash function.  Were it not for that, it might be desirable to fix some more serious problems, like the fact that repeated calls to a string whose `hashCode` is zero will take a lot longer than repeated calls for strings with non-zero hash codes.  That problem could be fixed cheaply via `if (hash==0) hash=length;` (since `hash` and `length` will likely be in a registers at that point, execution time should be minimal).

Comment: For short strings, the zero-hashcode behavior isn't a major problem.  If the `hashCode` were only intended to be used with short strings, however, there wouldn't be much point in caching it in any case.  The biggest danger from the zero-hash behavior not that `getHashCode()` has a one in four billion chance of not caching its value, but from the fact that a string which fails to cache its hash once will always do so.  Not a huge issue, but it increases the likelihood of certain programs sometimes taking abnormally long to do certain things.

Comment: Any performance problem that happens one time in 4 billion when you do something silly like hashing a HUGE string is (IMO) not a serious problem.  It is either a non-problem (because it happens too infrequently to be of real concern), or a problem that you can mitigate; e.g. by not repeatedly hashing very long strings, or by using a custom hash function.  It is not something that justifies mandating a more expensive implementation of `hashcode()` for the standard `String` type.  Java is optimized for normal use-cases not specialized ones.

Answer (score 4):

The point of hashing is to quickly map the result to an array index. If your hashes are arbitrarily large, you have defeated the purpose of hashing.

Answer (score 1):

HashCode is only a helper field for HashMap, HashTable and similar structures.

It doesn't have to be non-collision, it's only used to speed up the sorting process and lookup.

Having a perfect yet complicated algorithm is not neccessary, and if it's too complex, it would only slow down the process. Not to mention that some giant number isn't exactly practical for this purpose.

It's in a good detail explained on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

There are limits in practice. Your approach isn't able to provide reasonable

- computation time of a hash
- memory requirements

A perfect hash that is guaranteed to be unique for every possible element can't drop any bit of information. It may just shuffle them. For `String` you could simply use

```
BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(string.getBytes());
```

Calculations on megabytes of hash data will no longer be fast, you are basically comparing each object via `.equals` while the intention is that comparing by hash is much quicker because it does not compare every bit of information. That kind of means that hashmaps require collisions.

You should still use every bit of information to calculate the hash. If you would not you could end up with either less than the number space of your hash or uneven distribution where some hash values are result of an unproportionally large amount of input values.

Similarity of elements should not mean similarity of hash values. That's a point that you can probably improve in in most implementations but that would usually mean that you need to increase the computation time.

HashMaps work in practice so well that that extra computation time would have no good effect.